# How to make textview auto scroll at a certain time interval in android development

Tags: android

I have an application I am building and want to make the text in a textview auto scroll as a user is reading, I want to give it like a pace of scrolling, how to I achive it here is my code

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:id="@+id/contentScroll"
        android:background="#e2d0d0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView


                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvAutoScroll"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is the text in a text view how do I make it auto scroll from top to bottom when a user is reading"
                />

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to give your `ScrollView` a height. Either give it a fixed one or replace `wrap_content` with `match_parent`

Comment: i want an auto play text in a textview keeps scrolling down automatically without a user scrolling,